# How to test whether a pandas series contains elements from another list (or NumPy array or pandas series)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

Assume that I have this `DataFrame` (`Animals` column is of type `pandas.Series`):

| ID | Animals |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [cat, dog, chicken] |
| 2 | [penguin] |

And these `list`s (It can be `NumPy Array` or `Pandas Series` if it is better for performance):

```py
mammals = ['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'sheep']
birds = ['chicken', 'duck', 'penguin']
```

What I am trying to do is to add two columns to my `DataFrame` which are `ContainsBirds` and `ContainsMammals` based on the contents of the `Animals` column.

Here is the final expected output:

| ID | Animals | ContainsBirds | ContainsMammals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [cat, dog, chicken] | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 2 | [penguin] | 1.0 | 0.0 |

Comment: Having lists inside a field in a database is usually frowned upon. These models are usually represented with multiple tables. It may be a good idea to rethink your db / table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dictionary for test if match at least one value by converting to sets with `isdisjoint` and if necessary `0.0` and `1.0` casting boolean to `floats`, for `0, 1` use `.astype(int)`:

```
d = {'Birds':birds, 'Mammals':mammals}

for k, v in d.items():
    df[f'Contains{k}'] = (~df['Animals'].map(set(v).isdisjoint)).astype(float)
print (df)
   ID              Animals  ContainsBirds  ContainsMammals
0   1  [cat, dog, chicken]            1.0              1.0
1   2            [penguin]            1.0              0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension:

```
lists = [birds, mammals]
names = ['Birds', 'Mammals']

df[names] = [[int(bool(set(l).intersection(x))) for l in lists]
             for x in df['Animals']]
```

output:

```
   ID              Animals  Birds  Mammals
0   1  [cat, dog, chicken]      1        1
1   2            [penguin]      1        0
```